# Unable to get part of a play to run locally in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

This is all running within AWX which is hosted on-prem. I'm trying to manage some EC2 instances within AWS. I've setup the bastion jump and can get all my other plays to work correctly.

However there is one simple job template I want to provide to a few devs. Essentially when they make a change to the code, it enables opcache to be cleared and invalidates the specific files in CloudFront.

I want the CloudFront API Call (cloudfront_invalidations module) to run off AWX locally and then if this is successful, notify the two web servers instances to restart their PHP and Apache process.

```
---
- name: Restart httpd and php-fpm
  remote_user: ec2-user
  hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Invalidate paths in CloudFront
      cloudfront_invalidation:
        distribution_id: "{{ distribution_id }}"
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
        target_paths: "{{ cloudfront_invalidations.split('\n') }}"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      notify:
        - Restart service httpd
        - Restart service php-fpm
  
  handlers:
    - name: Restart service httpd
      service:
        name: httpd
        state: restarted

    - name: Restart service php-fpm
      service:
        name: php-fpm
        state: restarted
```

However when running the play it seems to ignore the 'delegate_to' action and instead runs the invalidation twice, for each host. I'm unsure if it's actually running locally. I've tried adding the run_once flag, but this only then restarted httpd + PHP on one host.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried separating out the `notify:` from the task that you only want `run_once:` on? something like `- debug: msg: ... notify: [...] when: my_invalidation is success`?

Comment: @mdaniel `debug` alone won't notify a handler because it does not create a `changed` state. Unless you also add `changed_when: true` to that `debug`. Or `changed_when: my_invalidation is success`, for the current matter :)